# How to make CONCAT_WS work while connecting through shell script

Tags: bash, hive

When i connect to hive and execute the following -

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('~',cast(col1 as string),cast(col2 as string),col3,col4) as row_key from table_name where date_column >= CURRENT_DATE limit 2;
```

it works fine.
But when I try the same from shell script -

```
hive --database db_name -e 'SELECT CONCAT_WS('~',cast(col1 as string),cast(col2 as string),col3,col4) as row_key from table_name where date_column >= CURRENT_DATE limit 2;'
```

it gives --

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:18 cannot recognize input near ',' 'col1' ',' in expression specification

Comment: can you try executing the query with double-quotes around it?

Comment: Tried a lot of stuff but not double quotes, worked absolutely fine, Thanks